# How to add a network adaptor in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, 22.04, settings

In Ubuntu 22.04.2 I am trying to add an previously existing USB-Ethernet adapter as follows:

[image]

but when I click on "Apply" it is not added. Nothing has changed. No new entry has been created. The screen looks like before:

[image]

I even tried to do that as root, but the adapter simply was not added.

Is that a bug in Ubuntu? In the settings? Is there a workaround? Is there a command line command chain to add such a USB-Ethernet device to Ubuntu so I can use it?

Content of file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Comment: Is the adapter connected?  If the adapter is not connected the system won't show it in the settings.

Comment: Yes the adapter IS connected, 100% perfectly sure!

Comment: It seems it works when I change the `managed` to `true` and restart the network. But even then it worked for some seconds, then it stopped working before it started working again after a minute or so ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: @waltinator No, my issue has nothing to do with a wireless device whatsoever.